# Show custom post type filtered by category

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, categories, wp-query

I would like to have a custom post type which contain several sliders for showing in each category page (exact category.php), one for each as planned.

All sliders were assigned to related category.

Currently I am using http://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/ to create a custom post type called: slider.

And I am having the below code for showing all posts from a category while pressing the cat name in menu. It works fine of course.

```
<?php $cat = get_the_category(); $cat = $cat[0];　?>
<?php query_posts($query_string . '&cat='. $cat->cat_ID .''); ?>
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        <?php the_content(); ?> 
  <?php endwhile; else: endif; ?>
```

But the problem is I can't filter the slider (custom post type) by category.

Once I call the `wp_query`, it rolls out all the sliders and ignores my get cat id arg.

Thought it should show only the slider in certain category, not all category.

So I am asking for a query to call the right slider only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have worked out on your problem and have come up with a solution(as far I have understood the problem).

It' works like this:

Registering a post type called : **sliders** with a taxonomy called **slider**.

This will create a post type where you can store all your sliders and categories them with this custom taxonomy called slider.

**CODE** for registering  the post type. (*this goes in functions.php*)

```
//Custom Post Type Sliders
add_action('init','post_type_slider');
function post_type_slider(){
    register_post_type('sliders',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name'          =>  'Sliders',
                'singular_name' =>  'Sliders',
                'menu_name'     =>  'Sliders',
                'all_items'     =>  'All Sliders',
                'add_new'       =>  'Add A Slider',
                'add_new_item'  =>  'Add New Slider'
                ),
            'public'    => true,
            'supports'  => array(
                            'title',
                            'post-formats',
                            'tags',
                            'editor'
                            ),
            'show_in_admin_bar' =>  true,
            'has_archive'   =>  true
            )
        );

        //Slider Taxanomy Labels
        $labels = array(
            'name'                  => _x( 'Select Slider', 'Taxonomy plural name', 'text-domain' ),
            'singular_name'         => _x( 'Sliders', 'Taxonomy singular name', 'text-domain' ),
            'search_items'          => __( 'slider', 'text-domain' ),
            'all_items'             => __( 'All Sliders', 'text-domain' ),
            'edit_item'             => __( 'Edit Slider', 'text-domain' ),
            'update_item'           => __( 'Update Slider', 'text-domain' ),
            'add_new_item'          => __( 'Add New Slider', 'text-domain' ),
            'new_item_name'         => __( 'New Slider Name', 'text-domain' ),
            'add_or_remove_items'   => __( 'Add or remove Slider', 'text-domain' ),
            'menu_name'             => __( 'Sliders', 'text-domain' ),
        );
        //Slider Taxonomy Arguments
        $slider_args = array(
            'labels'            => $labels,
            'public'            => true,
            'show_in_nav_menus' => true,
            'show_admin_column' => false,
            'hierarchical'      => true,
            'show_tagcloud'     => true,
            'show_ui'           => true,
            'query_var'         => true,
            'rewrite'           => true,
        );

        register_taxonomy( 'slider', array( 'sliders' ), $slider_args );
    }
```

Now as I have created the post type which will collect all the posts related to different sliders. Now the next step is to create a custom page which can show these posts based on their taxonomy selected. The best way to show is to create a taxonomy-slider.php in theme's directory. This page will automatically catch posts based on slider categories.

**Create taxonomy-slider.php** and paste this code:

```
<?php
    while(have_posts()):
        the_post();
        the_title();
    endwhile;
?>
```

Customize it the way you like.

**NOTE:** AFTER ALL THE STEPS. Visit Settings > Permalinks page. This will save the changes made  by registering custom post type.